# Excel getting max from multiple rows in second table

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have two tables

First table:

```
ML_ID   PID           Task Name Start   Color
1       PID1      One       01.01.2016  R
2       PID2,PID3     Two       #N/A    G
3       PID3      Three     01.03.2016  A
4       PID4      Four      01.04.2016  R
5       PID5      Five      01.05.2016  G
6       PID6      Six       01.06.2016  A
7       PID7      Seven     01.07.2016  R
8       PID8      Eight     01.08.2016  G
9       PID9      Nine      01.10.2016  A
10      PID10     Ten       01.09.2016  R
```

Second table

```
PID         Dates
PID1    01.01.2016
PID2    01.02.2016
PID3    01.03.2016
PID4    01.04.2016
PID5    01.05.2016
PID6    01.06.2016
PID7    01.07.2016
PID8    01.08.2016
PID10   01.09.2016
PID9    01.10.2016
```

For ML_ID 2 I want to find the max date for PID2 and PID2 with a lookup on the second table.

I made several attempts with INDIRECT(INDEX(MATCH())) combined with MAX(IF()).

I can still influence the data structure, if there is a better way. However, on the first table I can only have one row per ML_ID!

I guess the tricky part is, that I need either one or several lookups - depending on the number of PIDs in the first table.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is and what problems you're having --- could you provide more details?

Comment: By "max date", do you mean the farthest away in the future? or the farthest behind in the past?

Comment: Also, a quick note (it may help) - when I tried to use `Max()` with dates formatted with decimals, it wasn't working properly.  When I changed `01.01.2016` to `01/01/2016` (and Short Date format), the `MAX()` function worked (returning the date farthest away in the range).

Comment: @BruceWayne: Yes correct, the last(max) date. My problem is not the max function itself, it's more the issue to do a dynamic lookup based on the column PID in table one.

Comment: Hm - what formula do you have for the `max`? For some reason my index/match (with `Index(max(...))`) isn't working.

Comment: @xidgel: In row 2 in table one there are more than one PID. Let's say PID2,PID3,PID4. I want to find the max date in table TWO for the 3 PIDs. In this case this would be 01.04.16 (=PID4)

Comment: @heyhey33: Thanks for clarifying. Could you edit the question to show PID2, PID3 --- right now it says PID2, PID2 --- I found that confusing

Comment: oops yeah you are right!

Comment: There could be more than two PIDs in column 2?  How many, at most?

Comment: Could you force entries in the PID column of table 1 to be of a consistent length ? (e.g. `PID## `) That would allow you to use multiple `mid()` calls wrapped in `iferror()`. For example, suppose your PID Date List (column 2 of table 2) was named _PDL_, and you had at most 5 PID's in one line in Table 1:  `=MAX(IFERROR(INDEX(PDL,MID(B2,4,2)),0),IFERROR(INDEX(PDL,MID(B2,11,2)),0),IFERROR(INDEX(PDL,MID(B2,18,2)),0),IFERROR(INDEX(PDL,MID(B2,25,2)),0))`  The `mid()`s just snip off the numerical part of the PID, and use it as an index to find the value in the date table.

Comment: .....You would have to reorder your PID list so that they are in numerical order.  You could do something similar with vlookup that wouldn't require a well-sorted PIDvsDate table, but it would be even uglier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMENDED TO FIX A BUG. Thanks Adam!
This might work for you. Start with this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(Table2_PIDs&",","PID2,PID3"&",")),0,Table2_Dates)
```

entered as an array formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER). [Note: the &"," forces FIND to find exact matches --- searching for "PID1," won't mistakenly find "PID10".] This tests the members of Table2_PIDs one at a time to see if they occur in the string "PID2,PID3,". If NOT found, the FIND function will return #VALUE, which ISERROR will catch and cause the IF to return a zero. If FOUND, ISERROR will return False, so the result of the IF statement will be the corresponding member of Table2_Dates. So the function will return an array like {0;01.02.2016;01.03.2016;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}.

Now wrap the previous formula with a MAX to return the latest date of any of the matching PIDs:

```
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(Table2_PIDs&",","PID2,PID3"&",")),0,Table2_Dates))
```

again entered as an array formula.

The final step is the connect this to the ML_ID, which we do by replacing the string literal "PID2,PID3" with the results of a VLOOKUP of ML_ID in Table1:

```
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(Table2_PIDs&",",VLOOKUP(ML_ID,Table1,2,FALSE)&",")),0,Table2_Dates))
```

entered as an array formula. Hope that helps.

Comment: Very cool!  Small note: As with my inelegant suggestion in the comments above, OP does need to have leading zeros for PIDs < 10 (or less than 100, if any will be more.)  Otherwise, PID1 in the _Table2_PIDs_ list will match both PID1 and PID10-PID19.  (i.e.if the ML_ID only has one PID,  _PID11_, this function will return `max(Date from PID11 and Date from PID1)`  )  That make sense?

Comment: Good catch! I think I can fix this by appending a comma to both the find_text and within_text in the FIND function. That way you always have to find what you're looking for plus the comma delimiter. I'm amending my solution accordingly.

Comment: I didn't know about array formulas so far. Let me check your solution. Thanks in advance!